# Tool for Visual Studio or third-party tool to detect missing or unnecessary includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there any feature or extension for Visual Studio or any third party tool unrelated to VS that checks a cpp or header file and finds missing or unnecessary includes. Maybe tells which types can be forward-declared?
I remember Eclipse had a tool for automatically add the missing includes with a hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pokowaka.pokowaka-iwyu

'''
Include What You Use
"Include what you use" means this: for every symbol (type, function variable, or macro) that you use in foo.cc, either foo.cc or foo.h should #include a .h file that exports the declaration of that symbol. The include-what-you-use tool is a program that can be built with the clang libraries in order to analyze #includes of source files to find include-what-you-use violations, and suggest fixes for them.

The main goal of include-what-you-use is to remove superfluous #includes. It does this both by figuring out what #includes are not actually needed for this file (for both .cc and .h files), and replacing #includes with forward-declares when possible.
'''

Comment: Thanks, but this is for VS Code.

Comment: Then I suggest editing your question to make that clear.

Comment: @Newline the linked extension is for vscode, but iwyu can be used with many IDEs and tool chains. It in fact can also be used with visual studio.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you, I will look into it.